# How can I make my ember cli addon supply a vendor tree

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to make my addon supply vendor'd data to the app using it. The library is CKEditor (a customized version generated from the CKEditor builder).
I know I can use the addon blueprint to add a bower dependency but since CKEditor is customized I can't use bower to download that same version in the consuming app. 
I've used the **treeForPublic** and **broccoli funnel** to copy from my addon vendor folder the whole ckeditor folder to the app public folder (this is required by ckeditor).
My only issue is that the consuming app also needs to have the ckeditor folder in its vendor folder or it won't build because the watcher can't find it.
I was with the impression that if the addon was moving the folder to the public destination and was also importing js/css files in the **included** hook the original vendor'd folder was not needed by the final app.
Have I understood it wrong or can I do this without duplicating my ckeditor folder between the addon and the app ?

here is what I have so far :

```
included: function(app) {
    this._super.included(app);

    app.import('vendor/ckeditor_custom/ckeditor.js');
    app.import('vendor/ckeditor_custom/styles.js');
    app.import('vendor/ckeditor_custom/lang/fr.js');
    app.import('vendor/ckeditor_custom/skins/minimalist/editor.css');
},

contentFor: function(type, config) {
    if (type === 'vendor-prefix') {
        return "window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'assets/ckeditor/';";
    }
},

treeForPublic: function (tree) {
    var ckeditorTree = new Funnel('vendor/ckeditor_custom/', {
        srcDir: '/',
        exclude: ['**/.DS_Store','**/*.md'],
        destDir: 'assets/ckeditor'
    });

    return BroccoliMergeTrees([tree, ckeditorTree]);
},

treeForVendor: function (tree) {
    var ckeditorTree = new Funnel('vendor/ckeditor_custom/', {
        srcDir: '/',
        exclude: ['**/.DS_Store','**/*.md'],
        destDir: 'ckeditor_custom'
    });

    return ckeditorTree;
},
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If one creates `ckeditor_custom` folder in application's `vendor` directory error goes away?

Comment: Yes it works this way, but it makes me have 2 copies of the ckeditor folder. One in my addon and one in my app. That is my current working solution but I'm trying to improve it.

Comment: Did you try aceofspades's solution?

Comment: I just did and it doesn't work :( More information directly as a comment on its answer.

Comment: What is the full directory structure of you're app? is it the basic structure: [addon-name/addon], [addon-name/app], [addon-name/addon], [addon-name/config], [addon-name/node_modules], [addon-name/vendor] and your ckeditor_custom folder here:  [addon-name/vendor/ckeditor_custom] ?

Comment: Is this in a public repo to see the whole thing by any chance?

Comment: @jmurphyau: yes it is a basic structure matching what you described, including the  [addon-name/vendor/ckeditor_custom]. This is sadly a private repository.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
var path = require('path');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var concat = require('broccoli-concat');

module.exports = {
  name: 'myaddon',

  treeForVendor: function(tree) {
    var trees = [tree];

    var ckeditorTree = path.join('bower_components', 'ckeditor_custom');

    trees.push(concat(ckeditorTree, {
      inputFiles: [
        'ckeditor.js',
        'styles.js',
        'lang/fr.js'
      ],
      outputFile: '/ckeditor.js'
    }));

    trees.push(concat(ckeditorTree, {
      inputFiles: [
        'skins/minimalist/editor.css'
      ],
      outputFile: '/ckeditor.css'
    }));

    return mergeTrees(trees);
  },

  included: function included(app) {
    this.app = app;
    app.import('vendor/ckeditor.js');
    app.import('vendor/ckeditor.css');
  }
};
```

Comment: I've tried your solution from the vendor directory (after replacing 'bower_components' in your path.join() and I also tried by keeping your code as is and moving my ckeditor_custom folder from vendor to bower_components in my addon tree. I alway get the same issue : Attempting to watch missing directory: bower_components/ckeditor_custom or Attempting to watch missing directory: vendor/ckeditor_custom